# How should we handle our site's Logo?

Tags: discussion

We apparently have an opportunity to provide input into the logo. See other [StackExchange sites for example logos](http://stackexchange.com/sites).

**How should we solicit designs for the logo?** (contest, submissions to a meta question, etc)

Some suggested requirements:

- The logo should be easy-to-recognize, even at small resolutions ("icon-like")
- The logo should avoid being tied to a specific version of SDL Tridion (e.g. imagine if we the logo was specific to R5.3, 2009, or 2011). **Edit:** considering the feedback, maybe a classic logo would work.
- Anything else?

**Update**: I think we have an *approach* -- by upvoting submissions, reviewing designs with SDL, and seeing how we can include a boomerang or other familiar logos.

[Submit ideas in this other post](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34/46).

Comment: Do we have to worry about using a logo that potentially violates SDL's trademark's or copyright's or would their use here be covered under fair use?

Comment: Pretty sure this would be fair use, but I'll double check with legal.

Comment: Good point, @Glenn. I was thinking we'd create something that's "core" to the product--like a component, template, or some representation of "component presentation." But something SDL or product related might come across nicely.

Comment: It's also worth noting the difference between the company, `SDL`, and the *product*, `SDL Tridion`. The SDL logo and letters can't represent all of Tridion since there are numerous "SDL ___" products.

Comment: So you're ruling out a golden, shredded globe on a field of green? I doubt anyone will disagree with you on that. :-p

Comment: I have this strange desire to put together some sort of montage composed of Koopman's, van Puffelen's and Curlette’s shiny domes and propose it as the Site’s logo.

Comment: I have two out of the three you mention. http://www.createandbreak.net/2013/01/sdl-tridion-humour-part-4.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think we should start with one meta question in which we ask the community what they qualities the Site's logo (and design) should try to convey about the site. We should then follow up the first question with a second in which we solicite submissions of logos (and designs) which match those qualities.

I understand that SE has designers who will help with this but, for the second question it would also seem to make sense to solicite ideas from the designers at our various companies.

Comment: +1 and accepted for the *approach*. Looks like this question is getting the feedback on what the community wants (recognizable, include the boomerang, run it by legal, etc). We can start another question for "official" submissions.

Answer (score 7):

I know SDL will probably change logo's again in the future, but for me the current golden globe logo represents SDL and nit specifically Tridion. Using a "timeless" and recognizable logo for the Tridion product the one attached in this response is it for me.

It should stand out in the StackExchange site listing as well.

[image: SDL Tridion Logo proposal]

And we can overlay a small StackExchange logo on top of it as well just like they did with the Android Enthousiasts.

[image]

Comment: I like the boomerang one, even if (as Bart states) it's not the current Tridion logo. It does seem to change with every release, but the boomerang remains recognizable

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to incorporate a picture of a Tyrannasaurus Rex into the logo. For T-R(idion) EX(change).

And definitely +1 for the boomerang. It's been the Tridion icon for all these years, even if it's been faded into the background in recent official logos.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Hendrik that the logo should definitely recognizable and we will probably want something that works in small sizes too.

To keep inline with SDL's trademarks or copyrights I think we should consider passing our proposals by the legal and marketing department (Nuno and I can handle that), or even consider asking them to come up with a proposed design for us.

The logo Hendrik suggests is definitely recognizable within the community, it is unfortunately already outdated, as currently our product logo is:

[image]

But I like the ideas, lets keep discussing and suggesting for sure!

Comment: That's going to be difficult indeed. The logo surely will change again in time. I guess the community should adapt a recognizable symbol to represent Tridion the product and not the company. Like the little android robot and apple with a bite out out of it. We should probably keep it something with the boomerang, remove the golden color maybe to make it our own?

Comment: I like the boomerang--anyone know the meaning behind it? Three points representing the "Tri" in Tridion?

Comment: I think the boomerang is the most significant symbol of the product, and it is simple, small and recognizable.

Comment: I know the boomerang was called a 'swoosh' in our original company logo, I don't know if it had a meaning. You still see it coming back in the product icon of 2011, but it's fading away slowly...

Answer (score 2):

### Logo only when we get out of beta?

Looks like we get to use a design and logo only when we graduate from beta. That is what Robert Cartaino, Director of Community Development for the Stack Exchange Network is [saying here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55529/will-all-stack-exchange-sites-look-the-same/55542#55542), though it is a bit dated. Perhaps we have a little more time to resolve this!