# Submit Your Logo Idea

Tags: discussion

Distinct from [*how* we should handle this site's logo](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/how-should-we-handle-our-sites-logo), this question is asking for your actual submissions.

**Submit a small and banner logo as an image in your answer.**

We'll let votes and comment to help us decide with the following restrictions:

- We'll review with SDL legal and marketing, especially for anything that uses an SDL trademark
- We should also keep a copy of the original sources in a high-resolution (vector-based?) format if possible.
- We may postpone selection until after the private beta.
- 48 x 48 pixels for the small version (is this the right size?)
- 290 x 120 pixels for the large banner version
- We may want to combine and "redo" idea submissions to meet the above restrictions.

*(using image dimensions from http://stackexchange.com/ for references)*

See ideas and preferences from the first question on [how to handle the logo](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/how-should-we-handle-our-sites-logo).

**Update**: If/when we get to open beta we'll confirm approaches with SDL Marketing, open this up to the public, and choose a winner. We may still want to re-design the final suggestion to fit multiple sizes, avoid copyright issues, etc.

Answer (score 7):

How about something a little different? Disclaimer: it's friday!

[image: Trex]

Edit: Updated with Alvin's new version:

[image: Alvin Trex]

Comment: Maybe put the circle inside the logo like we did for PowerTools: https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/uuSnfL_32FDgVe18brPaCCAZ-443hcc4k4I5QGSTg_8?feat=directlink?

Comment: Yeah TREx and inside the circle, that I like. It is more us :)

Comment: I don't have enough privilege to edit Rob's post, so here's another version with a hand-drawn, copyright-worry-free trex. https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/SUB5hI5Qw043n-FVVYoOLCAZ-443hcc4k4I5QGSTg_8?feat=directlink I got the rough outline from this famous image: http://www3.canisius.edu/~grandem/whatisadino/pg%206%20trex.jpg, but we're free to make a better dinosaur head. We can play with color and contrast as well.

Comment: Edited to include your image Alvin.

Comment: you did it RSL ! you did it!

Comment: This looks great! ... although I'd also like to see how it looks with the ring.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Looking at the logo requirements, I think this could fit (it is the official SDL Tridion icon for 2011). I haven't passed this one by legal or marketing yet, but I have asked marketing to give us their opinion and ideas, so will post an update when available.

Comment: I think this one's better. No SDL mentioned, just a logo of the product. Excellent

Answer (score 5):

Evolving Rob Stevenson-Leggett's ideas with a new entry.

## 1 Roar!

[image: SDL TRex]

## 2 Cap and Ring

Added:

- The SDL Buddy's head pops out in front of the glassy sheen.
- Completed "dino-cap." More TRex-ish.
- SDL Tridion Logo ring.
- Sharper teeth.

[image: SDL TRex Pop-out]

## 3 Hands!

[image: SDL TRex with hands]

*This is a community wiki post; please comment, offer suggestions, and ideas or even offer an alternative on the same idea!*

Comment: Buddysaurus-Rex!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Had another bash at the concept we've been throwing around. Disclaimer: not a designer. Font subject to change.

Medium (168 x 168)
[image: TRex]

Wide (290 x 120 as per Alvin's dimensions)
[image: TRex wide]

Small  (48x48)
[image: 48x48 small]

TRex from here: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Trex_Roar.jpg
Font: Berlin Sans FB Demi

Comment: Simply awesome.